# how to select user which is not in two array of object

Tags: node.js

I am making a simple API in which i want to select user which is not in array of object.
I want to get user which is not in request and friendList array of object.I have tried with mapping but it repeatedly push the object into array.

API

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d",
    "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
    "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
    "phone": 9819339011,
    "profile": "https://eduzim.co.zw/news/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/6486/pictures-former-rhythm-city-actress-pearl-petronella-tshuma-set-to-star-in-good-men-meet-the-whole-cast.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
    "password": "Devraj 123@",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd4c1a675ce5566d3ee6df",
        "sender": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
        "sendAt": "2023-01-22T14:45:20.147Z",
        "status": "NA",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "6304e43b31ef2e7a4dec9251",
    "email": "devrajstha88@gmail.com",
    "name": "Devraj Shrestha",
    "phone": 9819339011,
    "profile": "https://i.etsystatic.com/5713076/r/il/db3028/660348889/il_1588xN.660348889_byu0.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
    "password": "Devraj 123@",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6304e44431ef2e7a4dec9254",
    "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
    "name": "Radha Shrestha",
    "phone": 9819339011,
    "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-03-26T08:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-08-23T14:27:43.249Z",
    "password": "Devraj 123@",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd500ed514da391523b7f5",
        "friend": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "me": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
        "acceptAt": "2023-01-22T15:02:23.379Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "630b5eea134f2e8b9d7f56d0",
    "email": "jeevan@gmail.com",
    "dob": "2002-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "name": "Rajib Shrestha",
    "password": "Rajib 123@",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/98/08/139808514282e8f491afee6b3768d8ce.jpg",
    "join_at": "2001-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "friendList": [],
    "request": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd4c1b675ce5566d3ee6e1",
        "sender": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "jeevan@gmail.com",
        "sendAt": "2023-01-22T14:45:20.147Z",
        "status": "NA",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "630b5f1a134f2e8b9d7f56d1",
    "email": "jeevanstha12@gmail.com",
    "dob": "2001-03-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2003-05-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "name": "Amit Shrestha",
    "password": "Amit 123@",
    "profile": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/50e2ebcf640e4aa38911078873baba79/tumblr_oc274g0Zi41va1j7ko2_1280.jpg",
    "friendList": [],
    "request": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd4c1c675ce5566d3ee6e3",
        "sender": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "jeevanstha12@gmail.com",
        "sendAt": "2023-01-22T14:45:20.147Z",
        "status": "NA",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "6314510e50d002c0e5aa074e",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7b/ce/11/7bce11dd52632801c864573812bf832f--trendy-mens-haircuts-men-haircuts-.jpg",
    "name": "Rabina Tandan",
    "password": "Rabina",
    "dob": "2001-09-08T18:15:00.000Z",
    "email": "rabina@gmail.com",
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "631452d0e1c2acf0be28ce43",
    "email": "mahima@gmail.com",
    "name": "Rajan Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-04T07:07:33.652Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "63145359e1c2acf0be28ce4c",
    "email": "manisha@gmail.com",
    "name": "Manisha Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-04T07:07:33.652Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "63145395e1c2acf0be28ce51",
    "email": "nabaraj@gmail.com",
    "name": "Prakash Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-04T07:07:33.652Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317f3db17ab46516a37a291",
    "email": "nabin@gmail.com",
    "name": "Prativa Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317f82b17ab46516a37a29c",
    "email": "nabinrai@gmail.com",
    "name": "Nabin Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317f85317ab46516a37a2a1",
    "email": "nabinrajrai@gmail.com",
    "name": "Himesh Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317f88817ab46516a37a2a5",
    "email": "mamata@gmail.com",
    "name": "Manju Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd4c1f675ce5566d3ee6e5",
        "sender": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "mamata@gmail.com",
        "sendAt": "2023-01-22T14:45:20.147Z",
        "status": "NA",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fa0c17ab46516a37a2af",
    "email": "mamatarai@gmail.com",
    "name": "Prakash Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": [
      {
        "_id": "63cd4c20675ce5566d3ee6e7",
        "sender": "dstha221@gmail.com",
        "receiver": "mamatarai@gmail.com",
        "sendAt": "2023-01-22T14:45:20.147Z",
        "status": "NA",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fa4117ab46516a37a2b7",
    "email": "mamatarajrai@gmail.com",
    "name": "BAbin Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:23:02.787Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fb622a4a331214a86a3c",
    "email": "mamatarajrai12@gmail.com",
    "name": "Maniat Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:59:43.137Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fb992a4a331214a86a40",
    "email": "mamatarajrai123@gmail.com",
    "name": "Mamata Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:59:43.137Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fe7b2a4a331214a86a4f",
    "email": "anish@gmail.com",
    "name": "MAnish Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:59:43.137Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "6317fea22a4a331214a86a57",
    "email": "anish12@gmail.com",
    "name": "Umesh Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "dob": "2001-02-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "join_at": "2022-09-07T01:59:43.137Z",
    "password": "Rajan",
    "__v": 0,
    "friendList": [],
    "request": []
  }
]
```

Js

```
router.get("/people_y_m_n", (req, res) => {
  let users = [];
 
  let new_array=[]
  const myEmail = 'dstha22123@gmail.com';
  userModel
    .aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "friend_lists",
          localField: "email",
          foreignField: "friend",
          as: "friendList",
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "frieend_requests",
          localField: "email",
          foreignField: "receiver",
          as: "request",
        },
      },
    ])
    .exec((err, docs) => {
      console.log(docs.length)
      docs.map((doc) => {
        console.log(myEmail==doc.request.sender)
        doc.request.map((val)=>{
          if(doc.email!=val.sender||doc.email!=val.receiver && myEmail!=val.receiver || myEmail!=val.sender ){
            new_array.push({
              email:doc.email,
              name:doc.name,
              profile:doc.profile,
              _id:doc._id
            })
          
           }
        })
        doc.friendList.map((val)=>{
          if(doc.email!=val.friend||doc.email!=val.me && myEmail!=val.friend || myEmail!=val.me ){
            new_array.push({
              email:doc.email,
              name:doc.name,
              profile:doc.profile,
              _id:doc._id
            })
          
           }
        })
        new_array.map((val)=>{
          if(val.email!=doc.email){
            users.push({
              email:doc.email,
              name:doc.name,
              profile:doc.profile,
              _id:doc._id
            })
          }
        })
      });
      
      res.send(users);
    });
});
```

I get the many duplicate object and new_array push details of all user,I tried to solve  but.How can I solve.Thanks in advane.
In API call

```
[
  {
    "email": "devrajstha88@gmail.com",
    "name": "Devraj Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.etsystatic.com/5713076/r/il/db3028/660348889/il_1588xN.660348889_byu0.jpg",
    "_id": "6304e43b31ef2e7a4dec9251"
  },
  {
    "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
    "name": "Radha Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
    "_id": "6304e44431ef2e7a4dec9254"
  },
  {
    "email": "jeevan@gmail.com",
    "name": "Rajib Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/98/08/139808514282e8f491afee6b3768d8ce.jpg",
    "_id": "630b5eea134f2e8b9d7f56d0"
  },
  {
    "email": "jeevan@gmail.com",
    "name": "Rajib Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/98/08/139808514282e8f491afee6b3768d8ce.jpg",
    "_id": "630b5eea134f2e8b9d7f56d0"
  },
  {
    "email": "jeevanstha12@gmail.com",
    "name": "Amit Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/50e2ebcf640e4aa38911078873baba79/tumblr_oc274g0Zi41va1j7ko2_1280.jpg",
    "_id": "630b5f1a134f2e8b9d7f56d1"
  },
...
]
```

new_array has following array of object

```
[
  {
    "email": "devrajstha@gmail.com",
    "name": "Deepa Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://eduzim.co.zw/news/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/6486/pictures-former-rhythm-city-actress-pearl-petronella-tshuma-set-to-star-in-good-men-meet-the-whole-cast.jpg",
    "_id": "6304e42231ef2e7a4dec924d"
  },
  {
    "email": "dstha221@gmail.com",
    "name": "Radha Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://www.theskinnybeep.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Versace-Man-2019.jpg",
    "_id": "6304e44431ef2e7a4dec9254"
  },
  {
    "email": "jeevan@gmail.com",
    "name": "Rajib Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/13/98/08/139808514282e8f491afee6b3768d8ce.jpg",
    "_id": "630b5eea134f2e8b9d7f56d0"
  },
  {
    "email": "jeevanstha12@gmail.com",
    "name": "Amit Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://66.media.tumblr.com/50e2ebcf640e4aa38911078873baba79/tumblr_oc274g0Zi41va1j7ko2_1280.jpg",
    "_id": "630b5f1a134f2e8b9d7f56d1"
  },
  {
    "email": "mamata@gmail.com",
    "name": "Manju Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "_id": "6317f88817ab46516a37a2a5"
  },
  {
    "email": "mamatarai@gmail.com",
    "name": "Prakash Shrestha",
    "profile": "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/7a/31/ab/7a31ab5b22ff3144e66ab42c3ba46040--short-hairstyles-for-men-long-haircuts.jpg",
    "_id": "6317fa0c17ab46516a37a2af"
  }
]
```

Comment: if you just want to remove the dupes see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects

Comment: No,i want to get all user which is not in frientlist and request array of object

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your question that you've done the lookup aggregations. After that you should be able to simply filter the result so that you are left only with users with empty friend and request lists.

It should look something like this:

```
const users = await userModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "friend_lists",
          localField: "email",
          foreignField: "friend",
          as: "friends",
          
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "frieend_requests",
          localField: "email",
          foreignField: "receiver",
          as: "requests",
          
        },
      },          
    ])
```

Now we can filter the users:

```
const finalUsers = users.filter((user) => user.friends.length === 0 && user.requests.length === 0);
```

Comment: Hi Debaraj, I overlooked part of your question and have now edited my answer.